# How to add project (.sln) into existing asp.net website files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have tried almost all methods to make new project using exisiting files of asp.net in vs 2010 but i failed to run on new machine.
each time i did this it shows error that "could not load project from d:\path name" etc etc that is my last computer path name

Now what i am looking for , i have a website and all asp.net pages but i am unable to see its working by single click on project exe .
please help me out that how i can make project using existing asp.net files

remember  : i have only asp.net pages to laod directly into visual studio but i want project exe so when i click on .sln file i can see site working.

Comment: Are the ASP.NET pages already compiled?

Comment: whay do you mean of compiled?

Comment: Do you actually have source code or did you pull this off the web server itself.

Comment: i have source code....and all asp.net pages including all files but i want to make .sln to existing files

Comment: Create a new project which will have a .SLN file and simple Add Existing Page and add all the files you have. Should work fine

Comment: no i have tried but its not working...

Comment: It looks like you are trying to add too many files... are you adding just the files that are needed. Like if you try to copy over a project file or sln file it will break.

Comment: ok I will add as an answer in a litle bit. Glad it worked for you

Comment: ASP.NET doesn't produce .EXE files. What are you trying to accomplish? Also, if this is actually a web site "project", then it isn't meant to have a project file. It's just a bunch of files on disk.

Comment: @JohnSaunders he was trying to recreate a .sln file so it opens up as a project and it kept failing because he kept copying the project and solution files from the previous project which essentially overwrote his existing one. Its working for him now apparently.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick here, but technically the .sln file handles a solution. A solution has one or more projects each represented by a project file.

Comment: @logixologist: and how do you know that's what he wants?

Comment: @JohnSaunders from what I could infer from his comments. Turns out its worked for him.

Comment: @brian You are right. And what it appears in his situation he for whatever reason needed to create a new project/solution.

Comment: @logixologist: good eyes. I didn't notice his response to you.

Comment: @JohnSaunders i was trying to solve it out by myself searching from different blogs etc but logixologist hint's made my mind and efforts easy to finally solve it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for it to work you need to keep in mind you have to use original source code and not pre-compiled code from the server. To import your old files into a .sln file:

- Create a New Website/Web Application
- Add Existing Item Select item(s)
  that you are trying to import into this new solution.

**Make sure you dont add any .vbproj or .sln files from the previous project.**

Comment: +1 but I would warn against ever using web site "projects". They are unique, but in a bad way.

Comment: this is a great solution